# How Can I reduce GPU time spent accessing memory in Deep Learning

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, multi-gpu

I'm using 4 gpus server in my school
I'm using pytorch

```
torch.nn.DataParallel
```

Library to use multi-gpu, I know it's not 100% optimized(ex. loss computed on specific GPU)
but My GPU has sufficient memory and utilization % seems to be fine.
[image]
But I still got high 'GPU Time Spent Accessing Memory' like below image.
[image]

And I found there's not significant change when I doubled my batch size 1024 -> 2048, I think it's because of high 'GPU Time Spent Accessing Memory(%)'

Is there any way that I can minimize 'GPU Time Spent Accessing Memory(%)'  and make GPU fully work on tensor calculation?
My env

- I read data from my local drive.
- My dataloader

```
train_loader = DataLoader(train_data_set, batch_size = 2048, shuffle = True, num_workers = 8, pin_memory = True)
```

- My ram is 240GB, GPU server policy's allocating 60GB of RAM per GPU
- I got 16 core. 4 core per GPU
- Preprocess only contain image(pixel value) normalization.